# Generic type parameters for conversion to parallel collection

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-inference, scala-collections

I have [this function](http://ideone.com/fwBOA0) to convert an `Array` to a `ParArray`, giving the number of threads as parameter:

```
def parN[T](collection: Array[T], n: Int) = {
    val parCollection = collection.par
    parCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
      new concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(n))
    parCollection
}
```

Now I'd like to make this generic, such that it works with collections other than `Array`:

```
def parN[S, T[S] <: Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]]](collection: T[S], n: Int) = {
    val parCollection = collection.par
    parCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
      new concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(n))
    parCollection
}
```

But [when I call it](http://ideone.com/arlTpK) with `parN(Array(1, 2, 3), 2)`, I get this error:

```
inferred type arguments [Int,Array] do not
conform to method parN's type parameter bounds
[S,T[S] <: scala.collection.Parallelizable[S,scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[S]]]
```

On the other hand, this is working:

```
val x: Parallelizable[Int, ParIterable[Int]] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with my type parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that this is a problem specific to `Array`: your method works for `List` or any other normal collection (except those with multiple type parameters, or none). Example:

```
scala> parN(List(1,2,3), 2)
res17: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3)

scala> parN(Set(1,2,3), 2)
res18: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[Int] = ParSet(1, 2, 3)
```

`Array` is always a special case when it comes to collections, because... it is not a collection. Because of Java, its definition is `final class Array[T] extends Serializable with Cloneable`. However, there exist two implicits, available everywhere, that can convert `Array` to a collection type ([`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps) and [`WrappedArray`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray)). And these types do implement `Parallelizable`, so everything should be fine... except type inference gets in the way:

Your type parameter is only defined as `T[S]`, so when receiving an `Array[Int]`, it will gladly infer `Array[Int]`, and then check the bounds: failure, `Array` doesn't extend `Parallelizable`. Game over.

I see two options:

- You can explicitly say that you want a `Parallelizable`:

  ```
  def parN[S](collection: Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]], n: Int)
  ```

  Or if you need access to the actual type `T` (in your case no, but who knows):

  ```
  def parN[S, T[S] <: Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]]](collection: T[S] with
     Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]], n: Int)
  ```
- or you can accept anything that can be implicitly converted to a `Parallelizable`, using an implicit parameter:

  ```
  def parN[S, T <% Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]]](collection: T, n: Int)
  ```

  which is the short version of:

  ```
  def parN[S, T](collection: T, n: Int)(implicit ev: T => 
    Parallelizable[S, ParIterable[S]])
  ```

All of those should work. In your case I would recommend the very first one: it is the most readable one that does the job.

Comment: WOw, beat me to it. The type-class pattern is the way to go here. However, don't you need to add in a `: Manifest` requirement to work with Arrays?

Comment: @wheaties no a `Manifest\ClassTag` isn't even needed because his method isn't actually creating an array (`Parallelizable.par` doesn't need a manifest, it always knows how to build a par collection). And in the case of arrays, it only wraps the original array, it doesn't even copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I ended up using a `<%` view bound in combination with `CustomParallelizable`.